# /dev/sda8: recovering journal... my linux crashes at boot time, the weirdest thing is the errors that appear below this message

Tags: boot

I need help with these problem, I researching about similar questions but any like my problem:

Linux version: 20.04.3 lts

After making some permissions changes for my user, my linux crashed, and when I rebooted, the following appeared :

[image: a picture of the error]

Comment: "some permissions changes for my user"? As long as you don't share exactly what you did, all I can say is "you've broken your software, reinstall and don't to it again."

Comment: I put the permissions 777 into my user, that was not the problem! I remember that I try to install mysql-server, and when I runned some command my linux was broken.

I need some way to fix it, on the computer I have important work data and a lot of work done.

Comment: unless we know what command you ran, *exactly*, we can't know how to fix it.

Comment: most likely you broke the entire OS and need to reinstall, but if we know exactly what you did, there is a *small chance* somebody can tell you how to fix it